# A gross of colored dots

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

The answer to this puzzle is a person.

[image: colored_dots]

Transcript of the colors:

```
GKWBGRWBYGCM
BRKYBKBRCKGC
WRYMCRGMBYKM
CWWCCMWCKYWB
WGKBMRCKMKMB
GRCRRWKYMYGB
GYMCGRWBYGCC
MYRKCKRGCGRC
WRKCMYBKWRWR
CWGBGWGMGYWC
RBBKKGMGWKCM
YMRWKMRRMYKM
```

Comment: The person is [Damien Hirst](https://www.artsy.net/artist-series/damien-hirst-spots). Obvs.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The answer is

> <strike>Damien Hirst</strike> **Louis Braille**

Why?

> If we first take only the red colour channel we get this
>  [image]
>  This is braille for
>  **First rotate 180 degrees**
>
>  Rotating 180 degrees and filtering everything but green we get
>  [image]
>  which is braille for
>  **Find the answer with a mirror**
>
>  So, finally also mirroring the image and picking the blue colour, the image is
>  [image]
>  giving the final braille message
>  **Born 1809 died 1852**
>
>  And, indeed, Louis Braille was born 1809 and died 1852.

Comment: Nice solve! @OP: you'd write 420 as "#420", not "#4#2#0". And there's a word separator that looks like this: ⠀

Comment: Yes good solve once again!